# TSQL: How to return two rows if Column = Null

Tags: t-sql

I have to build a procedure that returns a table at the end, which contains a list of fields where specific substances were applied. I need to return one row for each field and the applied substance. 
This works great for all fields where something was actually applied, but I also need to display the same amount of rows for those fields, were nothing was applied.

At the moment I get a table like this:

```
Field 1 | Substance 1 | 12345 kg
Field 1 | Substance 2 | 23423 kg
Field 2 | Substance 1 | 23236 kg
Field 2 | Substance 2 | 12312 kg
Field 3 | NULL        | NULL
```

I know that I could swap the NULL value with at least one Substance by making a Case-Condition, but I need two rows (one for Substance 1 and one for Substance 2) containing the names of each substance.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: It would be useful so see what you have tried. Which parts do you have problems with? What is the expected output?

Comment: What is your input dataset and what is your expected output?

Comment: I don't know what is your query but I think you have to use LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or maybe you have something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Fields (
    FieldID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FieldName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Fields (FieldID, FieldName) VALUES
(1, 'Field 1'),
(2, 'Field 2'),
(3, 'Field 3')

CREATE TABLE dbo.Substances (
    SubstanceID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Substance VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Substances (SubstanceID, Substance) VALUES
(1, 'Substance 1'),
(2, 'Substance 2')

CREATE TABLE AppliedSubstances (
    FieldID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Fields,
    SubstanceID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Substances,
    Quantity INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO dbo.AppliedSubstances (FieldID, SubstanceID, Quantity) VALUES 
(1, 1, 12345),
(1, 2, 23423),
(2, 1, 23236),
(2, 2, 12312)
```

Then you can use the following query:

```
SELECT f.FieldName, s.Substance, a.Quantity
FROM dbo.AppliedSubstances a
INNER JOIN dbo.Fields f ON f.FieldID = a.FieldID
INNER JOIN dbo.Substances s ON s.SubstanceID = a.SubstanceID
UNION ALL
SELECT f.FieldName, s.Substance, NULL AS Quantity
FROM dbo.Fields f
CROSS JOIN dbo.Substances s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM dbo.AppliedSubstances a
    WHERE a.FieldID=f.FieldID AND a.SubstanceID=s.SubstanceID
)
```

Or a shorter stranger version (with a different meaning if you have some substances that were applied only for some fields):

```
SELECT f.FieldName, s.Substance, a.Quantity
FROM dbo.AppliedSubstances a
RIGHT JOIN dbo.Fields f ON f.FieldID = a.FieldID
INNER JOIN dbo.Substances s ON s.SubstanceID = ISNULL(a.SubstanceID,s.SubstanceID)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but try this:

```
CREATE TABLE SourceData (
    FieldName VARCHAR(50),
    Substance VARCHAR(50),
    Quantity INT
)

INSERT INTO dbo.SourceData (FieldName, Substance, Quantity) VALUES 
('Field 1', 'Substance 1', 12345),
('Field 1', 'Substance 2', 23423),
('Field 2', 'Substance 1', 23236),
('Field 2', 'Substance 2', 12312),
('Field 3', NULL, NULL)

SELECT FieldName, Substance, Quantity
FROM dbo.SourceData WHERE Substance IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT s1.FieldName, x.Substance, NULL AS Quantity
FROM dbo.SourceData s1 CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT s2.Substance 
    FROM dbo.SourceData s2
    WHERE s2.Substance IS NOT NULL
) x
WHERE s1.Substance IS NULL
```